# How can I force the Menu to be in the window rather than the OSX default Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window that has a menu bar built into it, but whenever I implement a Tkinter code that creates a menu, it appears at the top next to the Apple logo. How can I make it so that it appears directly in the Tkinter window instead of the OSX menubar?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def NewFile():
    print("New File!")
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename()
    print(name)
def About():
    print("This is a simple example of a menu")

root = tk.Tk()
menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=NewFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=OpenFile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

helpmenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)

tk.mainloop()
```

Any and all help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Menu.add\_command() work in tkinter on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910640/how-to-make-menu-add-command-work-in-tkinter-on-the-mac)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm not sure I understand that answer entirely... Does that mean that I can not embed a dropdown menubar directly inside of the Tkinter window? Sorry if my question seems a bit simple, I'm just starting with Tkinter. @stovfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do what you want. When you configure a menu for a window there is no way to get non-native behavior.

What you can do instead is create a frame, and in the frame you can add `Menubutton` widgets. The behavior won’t be exactly the same, but with some work you can create custom bindings to mimic menubar behavior.